# variant of tower property in conditional expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to prove a variant of the tower property for conditional expectations. I would really appreciate any hints.
$$E[E[X \mid Y] \mid (Y,Z)] = E[X \mid Y] $$
Note that this proof requires no knowledge of measure theory, and all X,Y,Z are discrete r.v.
I am aware that $E(X \mid Y) = H(Y)$ is a random variable w.r.t $Y$, but I am not sure how to take the expectation w.r.t $(Y,Z) $
My guess is the following.
$$E[H(Y)\mid (Y,Z)] = \sum_{y,z}H(Y = y')P(Y=y' \mid Y=y, Z=z)$$  I am pretty sure that my statement above is incorrect, so how could I state this expectation more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your definition of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\sum_{x} x\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)$ (which agrees with the usual, measure-theoretic definition of the conditional expectation for discrete variables), you may note that this does not at all use the fact that $Y$outputs a number. We just need that $Y$ is supported on some countable set.

Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E}[H(Y)|(Y,Z)=(y,z)]=\sum_{h} h\mathbb{P}[H(Y)=h|(Y,Z)=(y,z)] 
$$
Now, notice that
$$
\mathbb{P}[H(Y)=h|(Y,Z)=(y,z)]=\begin{cases} 1 & h=H(y) \\ 0 & else \end{cases} 
$$
So $\sum_{h} h\mathbb{P}[H(Y)=h|(Y,Z)=(y,z)]= H(y)$ and you're done.